# Why is a stopped docker container not showing in 'docker ps'?

Tags: bash, docker

I tried to remove a docker image but was told it is used by a stopped container:

```
docker image rm 7bf111746926
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 7bf111746926 (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container ac3f2fe03cf5
```

But then `docker ps` does not show it?

```
 $docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Note: `docker ls` is [iiuc] a synonym and has the same [empty] result:

```
 $docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out: need `-a`

```
docker ls -a
```

or

```
docker ps -a
```